# 2x2 contingency for genomic feature enrichment

Tags: genomefeatures

I have an enhancer list and I would like to see how it overlaps with histone lists from different cell types (different sizes) significantly. I would like to use a contingency table for testing but not sure which format:

Should I use 2xk format

```
                         Enhancer overlap       Enhancer not overlap
-Histone Cell Type 1             n                       n  
-Histone Cell Type 2             n                       n  
-Histone Cell Type 3             n                       n
```

or individual 2x2 formats

```
                                  Enhancer overlap      Enhancer not overlap
-Histone Cell Type 1 present           n                         n  
-Histone Cell Type 1 absent            n                         n  

                                 Enhancer overlap      Enhancer not overlap
-Histone Cell Type 2 present           n                         n  
-Histone Cell Type 2 absent            n                         n
```

Comment: What do you exactly want to test? Maybe consider [edit] your question and clarifying the goal of this analysis.

Comment: the 2x2 is ok, you can test every histone (cell type) individually.... just control for multiple testing after

Comment: I think 2x2 is the easiest way. May be you are going to use fisher's exact test? Many tests that are designed for 2x2 cannot be applied to 2xk.

Comment: Some people would say that both schemes are inappropriate. The individual 2x2s are testing a slightly weird null, and the 2xk might be underpowered. If you're worried about this, I'd consider looking into multivariate categorical data analysis: https://journal.r-project.org/archive/2018/RJ-2018-015/RJ-2018-015.pdf. Contingency tables are still nice for looking at your data with human eyes, of course- for this purpose 2xk is more informative.